# Need advisory about HTML 5 chart and gauge components

Tags: asp.net, html, charts, export-to-pdf, gauge

I need to develop a web application in asp.net which needs to display 
-bar charts
-pie charts, 
-gauges, 
-grids
with HTML 5 support. And able to export the content in PDF format.

As a winforms developer im not familiar with web technologies. 
I have found these componenets 
-Telerik web charts-- i didn't see gauge control
-Devxpress-- no info about HTML 5 support
-Kendo UI-- low export functionality

Could you please advise some other components or comment these to help me selecet proper one?

many thanks.

Comment: I think that you need to search by your self on google, download the samples and check what is fit and easy for you.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same requirements (except that the backend technology could be whatever I wanted) and ended up creating the charts as images on the server. A bit memory intensive, but worked exceptionally well. I also created an old-fashioined image map to facilitate context-aware mouseover popups on the client.

The main reason I did it that way was, that whatever I tried, there was never a perfect fit between the chart as shown in the brwoser (with the added layer of difficulty that user could use whatever brwoser they wanted) and the PDF. Images ofcourse solved that.